# Android EditText accept 2 values only

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I want an EditText to accept two characters only, a one(1) and a zero(0). I was reading about input filters and know how to accept numeric values only but what about specifying which characters to accept.

Can someone please give me an example as to how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use something like TextWatcher, inside TextWathcer onTextChanged, if entered value is not either 1,0 display message.

Comment: I have an onTextChangedListener which uses a TextWatcher but i need to somehow specify a filter in the onTextChanged method or the afterTextChanged method, any idea how?

Comment: @Stuyvenstein, Please check it yourself. It will help you more than us.

Comment: Post some code you have, which help us in suggesting required change.

Comment: I have an EditText with an onTextChangedListener:
EditText ed3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     ed3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
          
         }
         
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
          
         }
         
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
          
         }
        });
Now I want to insert a filter for ex:
if(!(recievedChar.equals("0")) || !(recievedChar.equals("1"))){
    setFlag();
}

Comment: Add the if condition check inside onTextChanged. Refer this link http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/text/TextWatcher.java.html